# Which following sentence is the clearest?

Tags: grammar

*1.- Any one cup of drink is limited not to be over than xx.-* (currency)

*2.- Any one cup of drink is limited to be less than xx.-* (currency)

*3.- Any one cup of drink is limited to xx.-* (currency)

*4.-The price of any one cup of drink is limited not to be over than xx.-* (currency)

*5.-The price of any one cup of drink is limited to be less than xx.-* (currency)

*6.-The price of any one cup of drink is limited to xx .-* (currency)

*7.-The price of any one cup of drink is not to be over than xx .-* (currency)

[If not, what should it be? - I mean a client will not be given any drink which the price are over than the rate we limited. For example, £10 for one cup, they can not order any drink which the price is over than £10.]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Only individual drinks priced at under £10 per cup/glass are allowed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much. As I mentioned above, Do they sound unnatural?

Comment: Without modification (eg 'The price of any one drink a client orders must not be over £10') it sounds like the prices of all drinks, rather than what a client may order,  are limited. /  'One cup of drink' is unidiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If I say, _'The price of any one cup of choice is limited not to be over than £10.'_ Does it sound natural?

Comment: 'Over than' is ungrammatical, never mind non-idiomatic. 'Cup of choice' sounds like something from classical literature.

Comment: For more information, I created a new promotion for my coffee shop. It is one of the terms and conditions.

---- terms and conditions ----
1st prize: Free a drink for 1 month.
2nd prize: Free a drink for 1 week.
3rd prize: 2 free drinks.

- For every prize, you will receive one drink /day /person.
- The price of any one cup of choice is limited not to be over (£10, for example.)

@YosefBaskin

Comment: Do you mean 'one free eight-ounce drink (L10 or less) every day for a month'?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are promoting your coffee shop and want to give out some freebees, of course you do not want to give away the store. So, your offer needs limits balanced with friendliness.

You can use the following wording for simplicity:

**First Prize** - One month of drink-a-day, as follows: One free drink (£10 or less) every day for 30 days from the first day you choose.

**Second Prize** - One week of drink-a-day as follows: One free drink (£10 or less) every day for 7 days from the first day you choose.

**Third Prize** - Two free drinks (£10 or less)

Any wording that is overly formal is wording that chases your customers away with the feeling that your gift is no gift. Your challenge is to have reasonable limits on your offer without sounding like the offer has more limits than it has in value.

Comment: That means as I typed above is too much formal? Anyway, I do appreciate your help. Thank you for your kindness and did not make me hesitate to ask the following questions. English is not my mother tongue but I always try my best to use it perfectly as much as I can. (^.^)

Comment: What does it mean Karpoonka? I guess you want to type thank you in Thai, do not you? If yes, firstly, I would say how lovely you are! Anyway, about "Khop-khun ka", "ka" is for female to say something more polite, not stiff. It is always in the end of almost sentences except question (If you have heard something about Thai language, it sound like a music. It is too complicate to explain hahaha) For male is "krab". (In the end of every sentences.) You seem like my teacher. The way of your replies made me missed my teacher in Brighton when I went there last summer.

Comment: And now, what do you think if we both delete these side comments to clean up the page?

Comment: You can always clean up comments by flagging them as "chatty" or "not constructive".

Comment: @C - True that, but I wanted to remove mine, too, without criticism either way. I took mine out when I made that suggestion.